# I don't get alarms on my mobile but they do on the android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

how are you. I have the problem described in the title. The alarms launches correctly in the android emulator but when running it on the mobile they don't launch. It would have to send a toast with the message "salto la alarma" but the message never launches. The structure is as follows: I create in the mainActiviy an object of the Alarma class, which is a class that I have defined, and in that class the AlarmManager should create the alarm, and launch the onReceive of the broadcast receiver. This is the complete code: MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Alarma alarmaMensual=new Alarma(getApplicationContext(),"pastilla","mensual",2022, 2,17,17,41,00,1,1,null);
    }
}
```

Alarma class: (there are many fields that are not used since this is a minimized adaptation of the real application that I have)

```
public class Alarma {
    private int ano;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;
    private int segundo;
    private String pastilla;
    private String frecuencia;
    private Context contexto;
    private int nMinutos;
    private int weekOfYear;
    private String parteDeldia;
    private int requestID;
    private AlarmManager aMan;

    public Alarma(Context contexto, String pastilla, String frecuencia, int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo, int nMinutos, int requestID, String parteDelDia) {
        this.pastilla=pastilla;
        this.frecuencia=frecuencia;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.minuto = minuto;
        this.segundo = segundo;
        this.contexto=contexto;
        this.nMinutos=nMinutos;
        this.parteDeldia=parteDelDia;
        this.requestID=requestID;

        crearAlarma(contexto,ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo,requestID);
    }

    public Calendar crearCalendario(int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo)
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set (Calendar.YEAR, ano);
        cal.set (Calendar.MONTH, mes);
        cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
        cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        cal.set (Calendar.SECOND, segundo);
        return cal;
    }
    public void crearAlarma(Context contexto,int ano,int mes,int dia,int hora, int minuto,int segundo,int requestID) {
        String fecha =ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
        Intent intentoLanzar = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), com.example.pruebaalarma.Temporizador.class);
        intentoLanzar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Calendar calendario= crearCalendario(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, requestID, intentoLanzar, 0);
        aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //aMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        aMan.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*nMinutos, pIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(contexto, "hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

this is the broadcast receiver:

```
public class Temporizador extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context contexto;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"salto la alarma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and this is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pruebaalarma">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PruebaAlarma">
        <receiver
            android:name=".Temporizador"
            android:process=":remote" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve it, setting the application to "without restrictions" in battery settings.